# Any tips on localizing dates in .NET or in general?

Tags: c#, date, localization

I understand different cultures specify dates differently.  Some put day before month (27/10/2009 vs. 10/27/2009) and others use dots instead of slashes (10.27.2009 vs. 10/27/2009).  However, is there anything special that needs to be done regarding the year?  Do non-Christian cultures refer to the same numeric year (2009) as Christian cultures?  I created a simple C# app and did a toString on the current date, changed the language/culture to Arabic and it displays the same thing.  Maybe the year is a globally accepted standard???

Comment: See my answer [here][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351479/does-the-formatting-of-a-date-depend-on-both-the-users-locale-and-calendar-syste/1352216#1352216

Answer (score -1):

Use the `ToString()` overload which takes an `IFormatProvider` and pass in `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` and the date will format appropriately.

Comment: CurrentUICulture is used for looking up strings in resource files. You should use CurrentCulture instead.

Comment: Though I don't believe this will do anything to adjust into the Chinese, Jewish or Arabic numeric years.  My memory may be a bit rusty, but I don't think Windows supports any calendar (regardless of date format) than Gregorian.